# How to bring a running docker container again foreground

Tags: docker

I have a docker container running

```
sudo docker ps -a
```

result:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                PORTS               NAMES
0cd8d5166717        32bit/ubuntu:14.04   /bin/bash           15 hours ago        Up About an hour                        hadoop-test
```

How can I bring this running container again to -it mode and grab the terminal of ubuntu system ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can attach it:

```
docker attach 0cd8d5166717
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> to detach it again.

Comment: CTRL-P, CTRL-Q doesn't work for detaching AFAICS.

Comment: ^P^Q does work, BUT only when -t and -i is used to launch the container